# While driving in Europe, can I move into and share a lane next to a motorcycle?

Tags: europe, driving

I know most places in Europe allow (and sometimes even encourage) motorcycles to lane split and travel between cars. How do other drivers tell whether a motorcycle is currently occupying a lane as a car would, or is between lanes?

A hastily drawn diagram to illustrate. Can the red car in lane C move into lane B on the assumption that the yellow motorcycle in lane B is between lanes A and B? If not, would that change if the red car was a motorcycle instead?
[image]

Ideally I'm looking for an actual traffic law citation regarding this from at least one major European country, but anything helps.

Comment: Driving laws & customs vary significantly between European countries.  I don't think there is a general answer to your question.

Comment: Exactly which 'most places' in Europe allow such behaviour? I have usually only experienced motorcyclist 'between the lanes' in traffic jams and perhaps when waiting for a red traffic light. At least in the few European countries in which I regularly drive, this is perhaps to a certain extent tolerated, but strictly speaking prohibited.

Comment: If you do that in a car anywhere near me when I'm on my bike, you may well lose a wing mirror; it's *extremely* dangerous for the motorcyclist.  If you do it on a motorbike, you'll just get a really cold stare; there are very few fellow motorcyclists whose control I trust enough to have them ride alongside me in a lane.  All it takes is one piece of road debris or pothole that requires me to swerve, and we'll be into each other.

Comment: On basis of what do you assume that the yellow motorcycle is **between** the lanes A and B?

Comment: In UK absolutely not. There is no permitted or encouraged behaviour for motorcyclists to travel between lanes. If you see one doing so, hold your position until it is safe to change lanes, as always. A motorcyclist in a lane has the use of the **whole** lane.

Comment: In Germany, you need to leave at least one meter safety distance. You need to keep that one meter safety distance if the motorbike moves to the middle of the lane. Or to the side of the lane where you are. In that case you have to find space elsewhere. What you intend is highly dangerous.

Comment: @gnasher729 No, you don't. There is no legal requirement for one meter. And it is often even not possible to keep one meter side distance in the city.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's legal in the UK. Highway Code article 88 says "Additionally, when filtering in slow-moving traffic, take care and keep your speed low." and article 160 says "‘Once moving, you should be aware of other road users, especially cycles and motorcycles who may be filtering through the traffic. "

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo According to my google searches, every country except Germany allows lane splitting (aka filtering)

Comment: @Egor that seems to say that filtering is allowed, not that other vehicles are allowed to move into a lane occupied by a motorcycle.

Comment: @jcm correct, which is why I'm asking the question. The law seems to allow for a situation where 2 cars are occupying adjacent lanes with a motorcycle between them. I'm wondering what are the legal ways to transition into this situation. Could one of the adjacent cars leave and another take it place, while the motorcycle remained still?

Comment: Hmm, not sure this belongs on this Stack. I think what the law allows is for motorcycles to filter or lane-split but I would think it a bad idea for cars to move into a position that makes the motorcycle filter involuntarily.

Comment: @Egor that warns drivers to be aware of two-wheelers who are filtering in slow traffic: it does not advise two-wheelers that they are allowed to filter in high speed motorway traffic or for drivers to force them to do so.

Comment: This what surprise me in your example, what reason could cause you to come on the idea of moving from C into B? You're expected to drive on the right, unless you're overtaking, which you're not because other cars overtake you...

Comment: Who cares whether it's legal or not? It's clearly dangerous. Don't do it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think it would be very odd for the highway code to advise you to "take care and keep your speed low while doing X" if X was illegal. Wouldn't it simply say "don't filter" as opposed to "when filtering, do it in such and such way"? And I never said this is a high speed motorway.

Answer (score 21):

**No, you are neither legally allowed in most countries to share a lane with a car (some exceptions exist) nor do motorcycles in general tolerate cars well coming into their lane.**

I drive myself motorcycle since almost 20 years. Most EU countries do not allow a motorcycle sharing a lane with a car (one exception e.g. Netherlands), what you observe are mostly impatient motorcycle drivers who take the risk weaving between two lanes to get faster forward. In fact this strategy is very common if a green light has only a short time and a queue is building...which gets longer and longer. This can also be observed on autobahns when the traffic is jammed and the cars are motionless or driving extremely slow.

While <strike>strictly</strike> in many countries illegal, this kind of driving (if careful) is tolerated by most car drivers (and the police often also look the other way) because you allow the car behind to skip your position. Also you are always the vulnerable person on the motorcycle; if something happens, you are likely to be (heavily) injured or killed. For this reason, it is **always the motorcycle, not the car** who is maneuvering in a lane.

Now motorcycles are often driving in convoy; during this the motorcycles are driving with two in a lane in a zig-zag pattern which gives optimal distance and close into two columns when the convoy comes to a stop.

**Don't move close to a motorcycle with a car, this is a surefire way to aggravate the driver.** You simply have no crush zone as motorcycle driver and the mass advantage means that even a slow collision can break or squash legs.

Comment: I was under the impression that driving between cars in the EU was allowed iff the cars were fully stopped

Comment: @Eric it depends on the country. France and Austria for example allow it. Switzerland doesn't (yes, tecnically not EU).

Comment: Basically, when you're in motion, treat a motorcycle as being the same width as a car.

Comment: It is NOT illegal in the entire EU. In the Netherlands, it is allowed to drive carefully between slow-moving cars (traffic jam). https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/verkeersveiligheid/veilig-rijden-op-de-motor Dangerous is an opinion...

Comment: @RHA Corrected, thanx